# Django Prefetch not fetching the related fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have four models that reference a CustomUser table.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=140)
class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers')
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=70)
class Response(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='responses')
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Each question has multiple answers but each user can only pick one answer to each question.

Each user can answer multiple questions.

I have a ViewSet that authenticated users can access that is supposed to return a list of users with the same answers as them.

```
    serializer_class = serializers.ProfileSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        user_answers = qmodels.Answer.objects.filter(response__user=self.request.user)
        return models.Profile.objects.prefetch_related(
            Prefetch(
                'user__responses',
                queryset=qmodels.Response.objects.filter(answer__in=user_answers),
                to_attr='common_answers'
            )
        )
```

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    common_answers = ResponseSerializer(many=True)
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `common_answers` on serializer `ProfileSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Profile` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Profile' object has no attribute 'common_answers'.
```

I've added a print after `prefetch_related` and it is showing the base records properly but there is no `common_answers` field

Comment: Did you try using `SerializerMethodField` an fetching the related data with `obj.common_answers`? Maybe drf doesn't support named prefetch for some reason..

Comment: @mariodev Just tried it, same issue.